# Find the mode value of a column via a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort allocate the mode value of the given column from a CSV file.

The code I've tried:

```
    def mode_LVL(self):
        data = pd.read_csv('highscore.csv', sep=',')
        mode_lvl = data["LVL"].mode()
        return mode_lvl
```

Results in:
The mode value of LVL:  0    6
dtype: int64

I would like the mode value only, not wanting the 0 and dtype.

I have attempted to resolve by, but failed:

```
        mode_lvl = data.mode(axis = 'LVL', numeric_only=True )
```

Sorry I know that this issue may be simple to solve, but I've had issues searching for the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is necessary seelct first value of `mode`, because possible `mode` return multiple values if same count of top categories:

```
mode_lvl = data["LVL"].mode().iat[0]
```